# Cannot find module 'm3u8stream/lib/parse-time'

Tags: node.js, discord.js

is there anyway to fix this? I've been trying to resolve this myself but I give up

```
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'm3u8stream/lib/parse-time'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/rbd/pnpm-volume/71b5ddd8-2a78-46fc-aba4-68049f14880d/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/ytdl-core/1.0.0/node_modules/ytdl-core/lib/info-extras.js:5:21)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
```

Comment: Is it actually installed? `npm install parse-time`

Comment: ah, that's the issue! no it wasn't. thanks!

Comment: I also figured out that the dev for the package 'ytdl-core' did a new package update where they update the code to look in the lib folder instead of dist and was changed back https://github.com/fent/node-ytdl-core/pull/520

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This works for me, at the root of the project:

> cp -r ./node_modules/m3u8stream/dist ./node_modules/m3u8stream/lib

I really don't understand why, I assume is some bug of versions,  (mentioned in the previous comments) cause for some reason it needs the both folders dist and lib (with the same content apparently)

Answer (score 0):

Solved by: Chills

Comment: did you install parse-time?

Answer: no I didn't, I did get it installed but also I've learned from a friend about ytdl-core update required dist instead of lib

Source: https://github.com/fent/node-ytdl-core/pull/520

Solution:

packages needed installing: m3u8stream and parse-time

code needed in main file:

```
const m3u8stream = require('m3u8stream');

const parseTime   = require('m3u8stream/dist/parse-time');
```